# Duvida utilização do Sequence - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Possuo uma tabela no `oracle 11g` que por sua vez possui uma sequence

```
CREATE TABLE "BANCO"."TEXTO" 
    ("TEXTOID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NOME" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "VALOR" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATACADASTRO" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATAATUALIZACAO" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "TEXTO_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TEXTOID"))

CREATE SEQUENCE  "BANCO"."TEXTO_SEQUENCE"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 41 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

E possuo um script de inserção enviado pelo nosso fornecedor:

```
INSERT INTO Texto
  (nome,valor,datacadastro,dataatualizacao,textoid)
VALUES
  ('texto1','valor1',sysdate,sysdate,(SELECT MAX(textoid)+1 FROM texto));
```

Se eu adicionar os itens dessa forma em um script, vou estar quebrando a sequencia? Levando em consideração que a tabela não possui uma `trigger` para inserir o valor da sequencia no id do registro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim você não estará utilizando a `SEQUENCE`. Você deve adicionar ao comando `INSERT` da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO Texto
  (nome,valor,datacadastro,dataatualizacao,textoid)
VALUES
  ('texto1','valor1',sysdate,sysdate,texto_sequence.nextval);
```

A grande vantagem em relação ao max mencionado é que a `SEQUENCE` é **atômica**, garantindo novos valores únicos, mesmo em concorrência. No caso do max, você teria problemas com concorrência num possível rollback ou num commit demorado, onde outro usuário poderia pegar o mesmo `id`.