# Existe autoincrement no oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Tentei utilizar o `autoincrement` no Oracle e não consegui, existe isso no Oracle?

Segue código:

```
CREATE TABLE Pessoa
(
ID_PESSOA integer not null,
NOME varchar2(30),
ENDERECO varchar2(40),
CIDADE varchar2(20),
CONSTRAINT PK_ID_PESSOA PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT (ID_PESSOA)
);
```

Comment: O Oracle não possui um tipo de dado "auto-incremento", ele utiliza um objeto `SEQUENCE` para fazer `auto-incremento` de uma olhada [aqui](https://www.oracle.com/br/technical-resources/articles/addressing-use-sequences-oracle.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296361/how-to-create-id-with-auto-increment-on-oracle

Comment: como já comentado use `sequence`, aqui uma pergunta com um exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188883/duvida-utiliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-do-sequence-oracle

Comment: Sequence e Trigger , exemplos publicados

Answer (score 1):

Não e Sim.

Como disse o colega  [Zé Reis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/131377/z%C3%A9-reis-m-olliver):

**NÃO** porque:

O oracle não tem uma característica que se possa setar AUTO_INCREMENT

**SIM** porque:

O oracle possui a opção de criar uma sequência [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

Você cria sua tabela normal:

```
CREATE TABLE "db"."tabela" 
    (
     id_campo NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     NOME VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE    
     CONSTRAINT "id_campo_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("id_campo ")
   )
```

Ai quando você for fazer o insert você chama essa sequência que você criou

```
  INSERT INTO tabela
      (id_campo, nome)
    VALUES
      (customers_seq.nextval, 'texto1');
```

Para mais informações você pode dar uma olhada nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/188885/54152)

Espereo ter ajudado